# adding a header to a urlConnection in Android

Tags: java, android, http, header, httpurlconnection

I am trying to parse an XML file in android through an url api.

Although I keep getting the following error:

```
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at com.example.finalyearapp.Carbonfootprint.HandleXml$1.run(HandleXml.java:102)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I believe the file isn't found as I am not adding the header correctly currently I call the link this way:

My Stringurl:

```
  String url = "https://apis.berkeley.edu/coolclimate/footprint input_size=" + population +
                "&input_footprint_transportation_fuel1=1"+
                "&input_footprint_transportation_miles1="+miles+
                "&input_footprint_transportation_mpg1="+ mpg +
                "&input_footprint_transportation_bus="+ bushours +
                "&input_footprint_transportation_commuter=" + trainhours +
                "&input_footprint_shopping_goods_default_furnitureappliances=" + household +
                "&input_footprint_shopping_goods_default_clothing=" + clothes +
                "&input_footprint_shopping_goods_default_other_personalcare=" + beauty +
                "&input_footprint_shopping_goods_default_other_entertainment=" + entertainment +
                "&input_footprint_housing_electricity_dollars="+yearlyvalue+
                "&input_footprint_housing_naturalgas_dollars="+ yearlyvalue +
                " -H \"accept: application/json\" -H \"app_id: #\" -H \"app_key: #";
```

you can see the end of the url I have the header.

How I call it:

```
public void fetchXML(){
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlstring);
            HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connect.setReadTimeout(100000);
            connect.setConnectTimeout(150000);
            connect.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connect.setDoInput(true);
            connect.connect();

            InputStream stream = connect.getInputStream();
            xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
            myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            myparser.setInput(stream, null);
            parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
            stream.close();


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a header by calling setRequestProperty on the HttpURLConnection.

```
connect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Before trying to parse the reply you should probably check the response code and proceed on a http 200.

You should also take care not to share private data like the API key when asking a question here.

Comment: Unfortunately no improvement when I add this I still get the same error